# EmberJS not making a request to get data from rest api

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to integrate ember into my app. I want to replace a table that shows list of records with ember. I've got a rest api that will return the data for the table. However, the below ember code never makes a request to get the data from the rest api.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {

});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url: '/myapp/stuff/list'
    })
});

App.Response = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.attr("string"),
    book: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Below is what I have in my html page:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h1>whatever</h1>

        {{#each model}}
        <h1>{{author}}</h1>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

However, on the browser the only thing I see is `whatever`. I do not see the results from the API nor do I see a request being made to `myapp/stuff/list`.

My API looks like this:

```
{
  "meta": {
     "code": 200
   }
   "response": {
      "stuff": [{
         "id": 1,
         "author": "someone",
         "book": "some book"
         },
         {
         "id": 2,
         "author": "some author",
         "book": "anotherbook"
         }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK there are a few things going on here. First is that there is no route definition, that is where you specify how ember should lookup your model data. In this case you can specify an application route with a model hook that calls your api, like:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Response.find();
  }
});
```

With this in place ember will attempt to call your api. But the request will not be to the url you are expecting: instead it will call `/myapp/stuff/list/responses` since ember appends the pluralized model name to the adapter's base url.

Finally if your api returns the above json ember will complain that *Your server returned a hash with the key response but you have no mapping for it*. By convention the API should be returning an array of responses instead of a single response. The following will work:

```
{
"meta": {
 "code": 200
 },
 "responses": [
   { "id": 1, "author": "someone", "book": "some book "},
   { "id": 2, "author": "some author", "book": "anotherbook" }
 ]
}
```

I've posted a working example here (using a custom adapter that simulates your api response) http://jsbin.com/ICoYUxU/2/edit?html,js,output

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {});

App.Response = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.attr("string"),
    book: DS.attr("string")
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return App.Response.find();
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'App.Adapter'
});

var responses = {
  "meta": {
     "code": 200
   },
   "responses": [
     { "id": 1, "author": "someone", "book": "some book "},
     { "id": 2, "author": "some author", "book": "anotherbook" }
   ]
};

App.API = {
  '/myapp/stuff/list/responses': responses
};

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  url: '/myapp/stuff/list',
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    json = App.API[url];
    console.log('App.Adapter.ajax:', url, type, hash, json);
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: +1. However, won't adding the `model` hook to the ApplicationRoute cause the request to be made when _all_ routes are invoked? Instead, maybe he should use the `model` hook on the `IndexRoute`?

Comment: This is great. I can get a hang of things atleast now. However, how do i replace the local data with data coming from the api.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I just took the custom adapter out. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Mike can you put me in the right direction for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361785/fetching-content-from-rest-api-with-different-parameters

Comment: @Feech adding model hook to ApplicationRoute will cause request to be made once, when app is first loaded. This is necessary because the sample code posted includes an application template which iterates over that model. Since application template will be rendered no matter what route the user visits, the model data has to be loaded from the application route. Agreed that this is unusual.

Comment: @Anthony glad this helped, will have a look at the other question.